# Is it possible to handle one query but with different handlers using mediatR?

Tags: c#, ninject, mediatr

I am using ninject + mediatR. I have class that inherits methods from different interfaces:

```cs
class Query : IRequest<IReadOnlyList<QueryResult>>, interfaceName1, interfaceName2
{
    public string methodFromFirstInterface();
    public string methodFromSecondInterface();
}
```

and I would like to use mediatR to work with this query. Can I do something like this?

```cs
public class QueryHandler : IRequestHandler<Query, IReadOnlyList<QueryResult>>
{
    //first handler 
    public IReadOnlyList<QueryResult> Handle(Query message)
    {
        //something
    }
    //second handler 
    public IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel> Handle(interfaceName1 message)
    {
        message.methodFromFirstInterface();
    }

    //third handler 
    public IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel> Handle(interfaceName2 message)
    {
        message.methodFromSecondInterface();
    }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to send a query with mediatR to call second or third handler, not the first?

Comment: What prevents you from using three different query handlers ? This would respect Single Responsibility Principle and be directly usable with MediatR.

Comment: I used three handlers before. I was looking for the way, to improve my code and make it more elegant. I used one handler and one generic query for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, requests are dispatched to handlers by concrete request type. You would have to create derrived type for each request:

```
public class Query1 : Query, interfaceName1, IRequest<IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>
public class Query2 : Query, interfaceName2, IRequest<IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>
```

Than your handler would look like:

```
public class QueryHandler : 
    IRequestHandler<Query, IReadOnlyList<QueryResult>>,
    IRequestHandler<Query1, IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>,
    IRequestHandler<Query2, IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>
```

and dispatch:

```
mediator.Send<IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>(new Query1());
mediator.Send<IReadOnlyList<QweReportModel>>(new Query2());
```